# Laravel 5.0's Route::post renders an empty page, why is this when Route::get works just fine

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I am new to laravel and php. I'm trying to get basic forms to work but when I want to use Route::post() I get an empty page.
I have viewed multiple tutorials but can't find any differences between my (failing) code and the working examples.

My routes.php:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('index');
});

Route::post('creating', function() {
    return 'Creating something';
});
```

index.blade.php:

```
<br>
<form action='creating' method='post'>
    <button type="submit"> Create something </button>
</form>
</br>
```

I'm using Laravel 5.0 and XAMPP on OS X Yosemite.
As mentioned before:

localhost/test/public

will render a page with the 'Create something' button. But when pressing it, I get a blank page (url will then be: localhost/test/public/creating)

EDIT:
I have tried changing 'creating' to '/creating', this made no difference.

EDIT2:
Changing to:

```
Route::get(creating, function() {
    return 'Creating something';
})
```

and

```
method = 'get'
```

Does work.

Comment: instead creating try putting /creating in your routes.php file

Comment: I already tried this, it made no difference. But thanks for comment, I added it to the description.

Comment: Does it work if you change the route to `Route::get()` and the form method to `method="get"`?

Comment: If i change it to `Route::get()` and `method='get'` it does work indeed.. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the error logs (duh?!) I noticed the permissions for the storage/ directory were insufficient. 
After fixing this, I still needed to:

1. add `"illuminate/html": "5.0.*"` to the composer.json file.
2. add `'lluminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'` to the providers array, and 
      `'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 
      'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'` to the aliases array in the config/app.php file.
3. Add `{!! Form::token() !!}` to the View

This fixed the entire problem